# Using haskell's singletons, how can I write `fromList :: [a] -> Vec a n`?

Tags: haskell, singleton, dependent-type, singleton-type

As part of my journey in understanding `singletons` I have tried to bridge the gap between compile time safety, and lifting runtime values into that dependent type safety.

I think though that a minimal example of "runtime" values is a function that takes an unbounded list, and converts it to a size-indexed vector. The following skeleton provides length-indexed vectors, but I can't quite determine how to write `fromList`.

I have considered making the function take a size parameter, but I suspect it's possible to keep that implicit.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import           Data.Singletons
import           Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons
  [d|
    data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Show)
  |])

data Vec a n where
  Nil :: Vec a Z
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (S n)

instance Show a => Show (Vec a n) where
  show Nil = "Nil"
  show (Cons x xs) = show x ++ " :< " ++ show xs

fromListExplicit :: forall (n :: Nat) a. SNat n -> [a] -> Vec a n
fromListExplicit SZ _ = Nil
fromListExplicit (SS n) (x : xs) = Cons x (fromListExplicit n xs)

ex1 = fromListExplicit (SS (SS (SS SZ))) [1..99]
-- 1 :< 2 :< 3 :< Nil

fromListImplicit :: (?????) => [a] -> Vec a n
fromListImplicit = ?????

main :: IO ()
main = do
  xs <- readLn :: IO [Int]
  print $ fromListImplicit xs
```

Comment: https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *not* possible using Haskell because Haskell does not yet have full dependent types (although GHC [might in the future](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell)). Notice that

```
fromList :: [a] -> Vec a n
```

Has both `a` and `n` quantified universally, which means that the user should be able to pick their `n` and get back a `Vec` of the right size. That makes no sense! The trick is that `n` is not really for the user to choose - it has to be the length of the input list. (For the same reason, `fromList :: Integer -> [a] -> Vec a n` would not be any more useful - the size hint has to be something type-level.)

Looking to a dependently typed language like Idris, you *can* define

```
fromList : (l : List elem) -> Vec (length l) elem
```

And in fact they [define this in the standard library](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L178-L181).

So, what *can* you do? Short of saying that `Vec` has the length equal to the size of the input list (which requires lifting "length of the input list" to the type level), you can say it has *some* length.

```
data SomeVec a where { SomeVec :: Vec a n -> SomeVec a }

list2SomeVec :: [a] -> SomeVec a
list2SomeVec [] = SomeVec Nil
list2SomeVec (x:xs) = case list2SomeVec xs of
                        SomeVec ys -> SomeVec (x `Cons` ys)
```

That isn't spectacularly useful, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: _size hint has to be something type-level_ ; That's what `singletons` helps with though, right? Perhaps this would be possible with a type family `Length`, but the root of my question is I'm still a bit uncertain how to move things between type levels, and... Am I mistaken? That's what `singletons` does, no?

Comment: @Josh.F Not quite. `singletons` uses TH to promote term-level computations into type-level ones, and then machinery to go back down to the corresponding term-level (that's where the `SingI` stuff comes in). What it cannot do (since Haskell is not dependently typed) is let you go the other way. Here is a `Vec`-free formulation of the same problem: try implementing `int2Nat :: Int -> SNat n`.

Comment: My intent is to take the [TypeTacToe example](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6w79vy/type_tac_toe_advanced_type_safety/) and make it playable at runtime, which people seemed to indicate was [possible](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6w79vy/type_tac_toe_advanced_type_safety/dm82cfl/). The key thing to make it work is to get a singleton from runtime data, which this question was meant to be a representative example of. I seem to recall Eisenberg saying that singletons make most dep. types work in haskell, where can I go to learn more about the limitations/usage of singletons?

Comment: @Josh.F The key insight with the comment you linked is that the input arguments have type `Sing a`. So this is "runnable", if you fix at compile time all of the `a`s! [Richard Eisenberg's thesis](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis.pdf) is a great place to see what can be done today in Haskell (including with singletons) and what could be done in Haskell with his dependent type proposal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll plan on reading through that behemoth. Re: `Sing`, are you saying that it _is_ possible to write `fromList :: (?) => [a] -> Vec a (Sing n)`. I'm getting close, but just can't use this, and don't quite know what to do about `SingI`: `fromList (SS n) (x:xs) = (Cons x) $ fromList n xs` and `fromList' = fromList sing`

Comment: @Josh.F There simply is no way to lift the term-level length of the input list into a type-level `n :: Nat`. `Sing` only lets you go the other direction. What that lets you do (for example), is get the length of a `Vec a n` without explicitly traversing the `Vec`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an existentially quantified type variable, as in @Alec’s answer, or equivalently by rewriting in continuation-passing style. The trick is to give `fromList` a *continuation* (function) that’s polymorphic in the size of the `Vec`; then, within the continuation, you have access to a type variable representing the size:

```
data Vec n a where
  Nil :: Vec Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a

deriving instance (Show a) => Show (Vec n a)

fromList :: [a] -> (forall n. Vec n a -> r) -> r
fromList [] k = k Nil
fromList (x : xs) k = fromList xs $ \ xs' -> k (Cons x xs')

-- fromList [1, 2, 3] show == "Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))"
```

You can’t know the actual *value* of `n`, because it’s not available at compile time.

If you replace your `Nat` with the one from `GHC.TypeLits`, I think you can get a `KnownNat` constraint for `n` by creating a `SomeNat` from the runtime length using `fromJust (someNatVal (fromIntegral (length xs)))`, then get back the actual length value at runtime with `natVal`. I’m not really familiar with how to do it, and it might require the [`ghc-typelits-natnormalise`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise) plugin, but it might be a starting point.

Comment: Worth mentioning that these two approaches are completely equivalent and can be defined in terms of each other. `list2SomeVec xs = fromList xs SomeVec` and `fromList xs f = case list2SomeVec xs of { SomeVec v -> f v }`.

Comment: Is this called skolemization? (or related to it?)

Comment: @Josh.F: They’re related. As I understand it, skolemisation gives you a way to eliminate existentials in *argument* position, converting a rank-n existential to a rank-(n − 1) universal, while CPS conversion lets you eliminate them in *return* position, converting a rank-n existential to a rank-(n + 1) universal. “Skolemisation” in a typechecker also refers to replacing the quantified variables in a type with fresh type constants, for example when typechecking existentials, or more commonly when checking an inferred type against a declared type signature.